# Create an alembic upgrade process from configuration taken by another package

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm extending a 3rd party application which internally uses SQLAlchemy and Alembic.
This is good, because I need to extend the database model of this application but I don't want to fork the project.

So, I'm trying to use alembic in my extension package.

1. alembic recognize that the database is already using alembic, so I cannot just start a new alembic configuration in my package as it try to find the hash of the last alembic upgrade.
2. I tried to assert that my step depeds on the last alembic upgrade:

```py
revision = "my-autogenerated-revision"
down_revision = "last-revision-of-3rd-party-package"
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None
```

But alembic then raise an error has it cannot find the `last-revision-of-3rd-party-package` definition.

3. I need a way to configure alembic to use additional folders for looking for version upgrades.

Looking at the .ini file, I found this section:

```
# version location specification; This defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator" below.
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:alembic/versions
```

This works, I can use something like this:

```
version_locations = %(here)s/alembic/versions:/path/to/the/other/package/alembic/versions
```

But this is an hardcoded path.

Is it possible to generally identify versions upgrade from a package, in an OS independent way? Something like:

```
version_locations = %(here)s/alembic/versions:%(package:xxx.yyy)/alembic/versions
```